# How to add a button for minimizing the window?

Tags: window-manager

How can I add buttons in elementary OS so that I can minimize windows, for example, to the lower dock?

The lack of such a button is not convenient for me... if I go into a game and I don't need the Steam window to be on the screen, on Ubuntu I always minimize the Steam screen. I'd like to do the same in elementary OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on elementary OS 6 you should NOT install elementary-tweaks. The correct tool is now called [pantheon-tweaks](https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks/).

To install it, follow the instructions on their github repo:

```
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:philip.scott/pantheon-tweaks
sudo apt install -y pantheon-tweaks
```

Now, there should be a "Tweaks" section in System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the minimize button with the [Elementary Tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) application, you can install it by adding PPA support in Elementary OS running the following command:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

then running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

Comment: AFAIK The Tweaks application is considered dangerous by elementary devs.

Comment: There is a new version of this software (`pantheon-tweaks`, from the same repository), this is no longer the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize windows with the keyboard shortcut `Super+H` (Super is typically your Windows key).

Alternatively, you can click the dock icon to minimize a focused window.

Answer (score 0):

As Vitor mentioned, you can install Elementary Tweaks (by  his method.)  When viewed under system settings there is an option to have either Windows or Mac style Window Controls, as well as various Linux flavors. (System Settings:Tweaks:Appearance:Window Controls:Layout)

This is system wide, however some programs will override it.  For instance I use Brave for a web browser, and it uses its own theme including Window Controls.